# how to get a cell to use in a formula excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to get where the =LARGE formula got the figure from, so that I can then grab the cells to the right of it.

Basically I have a list of 100 scores, with hits and golds and the persons name next to it.

I am using =LARGE(A1:A100,1) to get the highest number, but then I am wanting to know how I can find the cell its got it from, so I can then get the 3 cells to the right of it.

So for example, if the highest figure is in A10 say, how can I find this out from the LARGE formula?

Thanks,

Doomie

Answer (score 1):

You can use **MATCH()** to find the row:

```
=MATCH(LARGE(A1:A100,1),A1:A100,0)
```

Or you can use **VLOOKUP()** to both find the value and retrieve its companion cell

Comment: Hi,  I have tried this, but all its coming up with is the number 2, the highest number at the moment is in A4.